# Cannot connect from Jenkins to Github

Tags: jenkins-github-plugin

In Jenkins, I am using the following github URL "https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart.git". Using user-id and password mechanism. As string password didn't seem to work, create a public access token (classic) in github.com and updated password in jenkins with that token string.
I am still having issues connecting Jenkins with Github and same error message comes as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvt44.png)

Can someone kindly help? What does the HEAD word signify and most importantly how do i resolve this issue?

Thanks
Rajib

Tried using both direct github.com password as well as using the public access token (classic) , neither worked unfortunately.